# Debug Counter Code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, counter

I have a website that I inherited as a web designer that has a counter on it that is not work. The site runs on Wordpress 4.5.2 and the counter consists of three parts. It should appear on this page https://electratherm.com/ above Cumulative Fleet Runtime.

The first part is just a div tag that is on this page:

```
<div id="counter" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

The second section is edited by the client, it shows up towards the bottom of the source code:

```
<script>
//update next three variables once per week using current fleet data

var START_DATE = new Date("June 5, 2016 23:59:00"); 

// the date and time when run hours were known

var START_VALUE = 548047; 

// the run hours known at the date above

var INCREMENT = 0.0041; 

// 4000 fleet hrs per week = .0050 per sec, how many fleet run hours are added every second of the day. # of week hours / 7/24/60/60
</script>
```

The third part is the actual javascript file which is linked lower in the source code:

```
<script src="https://electratherm-electratherm.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/js/counter.js" type="text/javascript">

// section for fleet hours counter here
//update next three variables once per week using current fleet data
//var START_DATE = new Date("February 17, 2015 23:59:00"); // the date and time when run hours were known
//var START_VALUE = 316398; // the run hours known at the date above
//var INCREMENT = 0.0055; // 4000 fleet hrs per week = .0066 per sec, how many fleet run hours are added every second of the day

var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var count = 0;
var fleetyears = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 fleetyears = count / 8766;

 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "<div class='w-counter-number'>" + Number((2)).toLocaleString('en') + " HOURS</div>"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 window.setInterval( function(){
  count += INCREMENT; 
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "<div class='w-counter-number'>" + Number(count.toFixed()).toLocaleString('en') + " HOURS</div>"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 }, msInterval);
});
 /*
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed()).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 window.setInterval( function(){
  count += INCREMENT; 
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Cumulative Fleet Runtime: " + Number(count.toFixed()).toLocaleString('en') + " hours (" + Number(fleetyears.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en') + " years)&nbsp;"; //simply 'count' if unformatted
 }, msInterval);
});*/

This was working not to long ago but it stopped now. Not sure what is going on but I don't see any errors in the Debug console in Firefox.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a jQuery error on your page.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .w-nav-item

I would guess that you were changing the nav recently?  If that is the case, something you did there is causing jQuery to break, and once a JavaScript error is thrown, the rest can be very unreliable.  I read through the code you posted and didn't notice any glaring errors.

As for fixing the error, look through your href's in your nav and make sure you aren't using any special characters.

Comment: I haven’t checked anything, but this doesn't look like a jQuery error but rather as some accidentally typed `$(.w-nav-item)`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is never calling the ready function.

You seem to have an issue in your plugins.js file on this line:

```
jQuery('.w-nav-item a[href*=#]').parents('.w-nav-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
```

I believe it's caused by the # not being properly escaped like so:

```
jQuery('.w-nav-item a[href*=\\#]').parents('.w-nav-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
```

This 'may' be what's preventing jQuery from executing it's ready function, but until it's fixed I can't tell.